# SMS Blocked Unregistered Number: Just discovered that many of our SMS Messages are blocked. Registration of Campaign Requested. Interim Options?

Tags: sms

We manage youth exhibitor animal auctions for county fairs. We use twilio SMS messages to verify customer accounts and winning auction bids. Just discovered that many of our SMS messages are being blocked as the A2P 10DLC number is not Registered. I completed the registration process and requested a Campaign registration, but it says that could take 2-3 weeks to complete? Do we have any other options? Is there an escalation process to get quicker approval?

Send SMS via API's and check logs to see "Error 30034 US A2P 10DLC - Message from an Unregistered Number"